# How to convert List<List<Double>> to List<Double[]> and to List<double[]> with Java 8 stream API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I got stuck with this problem.
I've found similar answers here, but none of those solves the problem.
Should I use mapToDouble() here? Is there anything like "mapToDoubleArray"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a `List<List<Double>>` into a `List<double[]>`, you need to map each inner list into a double array using `mapToDouble` combined with `toArray()` (which is the "mapToDoubleArray" operation you are looking for).

```
List<double[]> res = 
    myList.stream()
          .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).toArray())
          .collect(toList());
```

If you want a `List<Double[]>` instead, you can simply use `.map(list -> list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]))`.